# SalesForce SmartStore not working above android version 2.2

Tags: soql, salesforce2salesforce

please help me to implement Smartstore using Salesforce sdk for above android version 2.2. I have tried to run SmartStore app on android version 4.0 device, but it gives me exception
        "info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteException: not an error"

I think i am using old SqlChipper jar file or maybe some other reason. But app is working fine on 2.2 or below devices.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you could tell us what you've done to troubleshoot the problem, you're more likely to get a helpful response. It does sound to me from the error message that your problem is indeed related to SQL, so it very well could be that an out of date SQL cipher jar file could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: please can you tell me the latest SQL chipper jar file version. so i can download this and try to use this.

Comment: Sorry, but neither SQL or Android apps are my area. Google can be your best friend when trying to locate such things.